# Passing argv to gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I am running gdb in the following way:

```
gdb $file "My Arg here" --ex "source .breakpoints_$file.c" --ex 'r' --ex 'set confirm off'
```

Yet I get the following in the program:

```
─── Variables ───────────────────────────────────
arg argc = 1, argv = 0x7fffffffe1d8: 47 '/'
```

Meaning it's not picking up the `argv`. How would I properly pass cmd line args to gdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by passing the `args` argument to `gdb`. For example:

```
gdb --ex "source .breakpoints_$file.c" --ex 'r' --ex 'set confirm off' \
    --args $file "An argument" another
```

And now we get:

```
─── Variables ──────────────────────────────
arg argc = 3, argv = 0x7fffffffe1b8: 47 '/'

>>> p argv[1]
$1 = 0x7fffffffe49c "An argument"
>>> p argv[2]
$2 = 0x7fffffffe4a8 "another"
```